# Symfony Access restriction to CRUD actions

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have simply CRUD function generated by symfony.
There is article class and article owner.
I want to prevent other users than owner of current article tu edit it.
I was thinking about custom my own filter or validator but when i will implement validator some of the users can enter into edit form (they couldn't only sent it).
But when I will implement user filter there will be problem to make filter execute only before some actions (edit in this case).

How should i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is built-in. You should read about the [security.yml](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/08-Security) file.

UPDATE: I see... apparently the security system [calls the method `hasCredential()` of the user object](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/12-Filters#chapter_12_security). Maybe you could extend tthis method in your custom user class, so that it does a special check when its parameter is, for instance, 'article_owner'.

Once this is done, all you'll have to do is specify this credential for the actions you want

Comment: I know what it is. But I should made for example. "all:
  credentials: owner_article_5" for all of the articles... Ant i dont know how specify credentials to each owner.

Comment: Nice :] I have alredy writen a method "isOwner" in my action class. But solution witch you suggest is nice and clever. I think that overload of users class is good thing for that problem.

Comment: This way, you can use it in several actions, without copying/pasting code... :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think symfony supports Object level access control out of the box. I had that particular problem in one of my applications and I ended up doing explicit check whether the logged in user matches the owner in the edit action. This is the function I used for that:

```
protected function hasObjectAccess($obj) {
    if ($this->getUser()->hasGroup('admin')
        || $obj->getOwnerId() == $this->getUser()->getId()))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```